# How can I avoid the monster chasing me onto the bridge?

Tags: temple-run-2

It appears as though I'm stumbling/tripping over something when I get to the wooden bridge, but I can't figure out what that 'something' is. The gorilla/ape/monster thing comes chasing after me and will oftentimes gobble me up, and I can't figure out how to prevent this from happening. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried jumping right before? That might help you clear the obstacle if there is one, but since the game doesn't really keep level designs, it is hard to know what the problem actually is.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine it' is some kind of tripwire between two "torches". Keep a look out for the flames on the side of the bridge and jump between them. I've tried several times to catch a screenshot, but I'm too slow.

Answer (score 0):

It's something that is not very obvious, there are some lighter spots, but I often triple something on wooden bridge without noticing it.

The best way for me is to spare bolt run for a while when I suppose the terrain will change, because it's life-saver on that location!